# Autocomplete js - The list's scrollbar's list down arrow flickers

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have an autocomplete list and the list's scrollbar's down arrow is setting focus to first element, it flickers. While scrolling with mouse is working fine.
**Using jquery 3.4.1.**

```
 .ui-autocomplete {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     cursor: default;
  }
```

The issue is only bottom arrow in auto complete list scroll bars:
[image]

Comment: Show us your code please

Comment: @IvanD Added code

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you have shared complete code, may be you have issue in other place in your project. Following code is working fine:

```js
$(function() {
  var availableTags = [
    "ActionScript",
    "AppleScript",
    "Asp",
    "BASIC",
    "C",
    "C++",
    "Clojure",
    "COBOL",
    "ColdFusion",
    "Erlang",
    "Fortran",
    "Groovy",
    "Haskell",
    "Java",
    "JavaScript",
    "Lisp",
    "Perl",
    "PHP",
    "Python",
    "Ruby",
    "Scala",
    "Scheme"
  ];
  $("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
  });
});
```

```css
.ui-autocomplete {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  cursor: default;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
  <h1>Demo</h1>
</div>
```